# Drop-down navigation - menu flickering on mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/deswolf/D9X53/
If you play around with this menu for a little bit, you will notice that when your mouse leaves at the top, you get a lot of flickering, which is really annoying. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by flickering? It seems to work fine for me in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: When you hover over "drop-down" and hover on "link no-1.2" then move your mouse to the right on the white place, and move it back on the link it starts to flicker.

Comment: I think it's a browser bug. You can't fix that

Comment: You can still sort of fix it by allowing the menu to fully roll up (disable the mouseenter event) before it can roll back down again.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're having happens when you go back to the menu while it's still rolling up. I updated your code to disable the `mouseenter` event for 500ms (enough to allow the menu to roll up) and then enable it again. This prevents you from triggering the `mouseenter` event (which causes it to roll down) while it's still rolling up.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D9X53/1/)